# Why when im using the variable t it doesn't show anything?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code of form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string readableRss;
        string t = "";
        int counter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            readableRss = RssReader.covertRss("http://rotter.net/rss/rotternews.xml");
            string[] lines = Regex.Split(readableRss, "\r\n");
            this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed = new string[lines.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                counter += 1;
                if (counter <= 5)
                {
                    t = Convert.ToString(lines[i]);
                    SetupText(new string[] { t,t,t,t,t });
                }
                else
                {
                    counter = 0;
                }

                this.newsFeed1.TextColor = new Color[5];
                SetupColors(new Color[] { Color.Blue, Color.Lime, Color.Maroon, Color.FromArgb(255, 71, 71, 255), Color.BurlyWood });
                this.newsFeed1.Spacing = this.newsFeed1.Height;
                this.newsFeed1.SetTexts();
                this.newsFeed1.startFeed();
            }
        }

        private void SetupColors(Color[] colors)
        {
              if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 0 && colors.Length > 0)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[0] = colors[0];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 1 && colors.Length > 1)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[1] = colors[1];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 2 && colors.Length > 2)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[2] = colors[2];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 3 && colors.Length > 3)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[3] = colors[3];
               if (this.newsFeed1.TextColor.Length > 4 && colors.Length > 4)
                   this.newsFeed1.TextColor[4] = colors[4];
        }

        private void SetupText(string[] textToDisplay)
        {
             if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 0 && textToDisplay.Length > 0)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[0] = textToDisplay[0];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 1 && textToDisplay.Length > 1)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[1] = textToDisplay[1];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 2 && textToDisplay.Length > 2)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[2] = textToDisplay[2];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 3 && textToDisplay.Length > 3)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[3] = textToDisplay[3];
              if (this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed.Length > 4 && textToDisplay.Length > 4)
                  this.newsFeed1.NewsTextFeed[4] = textToDisplay[4];
        }
    }
}
```

readableRss is a string

When i enter to the SetupText(new string[] {
The variable t once or 5 times it doesn't show anything on the UserControl.
But if for a test i switch the first t with "hi" then i see the "hi" in the UserControl.

Why when using the variable t it doesn't show anything but when im using "hi" it does ?
t is also a string.

This is the code of the class NewsFeed(newsFeed1 variable):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace RssNews
{
    public partial class NewsFeed : UserControl
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer speaker;
        Label[] list = new Label[5];
        int jump = 0;

        public string[] NewsTextFeed { get; set; }
        public Color[] TextColor { get; set; }

        private int _spacing = 10;
        public int Spacing
        {
            get { return _spacing; }
            set { _spacing = value; }
        }

        public NewsFeed()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            speaker = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            Init();
        }

        private void Init()
        {
            // Initialise Position Variables 
            int x = 2;
            int y = this.Height; // just out of view at top. 

            // Assign each label in list the following properties 
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                list[i] = new Label();
                list[i].AutoSize = false;
                list[i].Location = new Point(x, y + (_spacing * i)); // The math is the UserControl size for example 150x150 and then 150/the number of labels for example 150/5=30 so it will be 30 * i \\
                this.Controls.Add(list[i]); // Add control to UserControl 
            }
            startFeed();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Label label in list)
            // Loop through List with for-each 
            {
                // Move label up 'jump' pixels 
                label.Location = new Point(label.Location.X, label.Location.Y - jump);

                // Check to see if out of view. 
                if (label.Location.Y <= -_spacing)
                {
                    //calculate the new Y-Position by summing all heights + the sum of _spacing - 1 time spacing, cause it is now at the ypoint -spacing
                    int newPosY = list.Sum((b) => (b.Height));
                    label.Location = new Point(label.Location.X, newPosY + _spacing * (list.Length - 1));
                }
            }
        }

        public void SetTexts()
        {
            if (list.Length > 4 && NewsTextFeed != null)
            {
                //get the label at this position in the list
                //and assign some text
                if (list[0] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[0] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 0)
                    list[0].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[0];
                //  speaker.SpeakAsync(list[0].Text); // this is where we make the text to speech...to add option for it yes or not using the option in form1.
                if (list[1] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[1] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 1)
                    list[1].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[1];

                if (list[2] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[2] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 2)
                    list[2].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[2];

                if (list[3] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[3] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 3)
                    list[3].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[3];

                if (list[4] != null && this.NewsTextFeed[4] != null && NewsTextFeed.Length > 4)
                    list[4].Text = this.NewsTextFeed[4];
            }

            if (list.Length > 4 && TextColor != null)
            {
                if (list[0] != null && TextColor.Length > 0 && !TextColor[0].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[0].ForeColor = TextColor[0];

                if (list[1] != null && TextColor.Length > 1 && !TextColor[1].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[1].ForeColor = TextColor[1];

                if (list[2] != null && TextColor.Length > 2 && !TextColor[2].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[2].ForeColor = TextColor[2];

                if (list[3] != null && TextColor.Length > 3 && !TextColor[3].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[3].ForeColor = TextColor[3];

                if (list[4] != null && TextColor.Length > 4 && !TextColor[4].Equals(Color.Transparent))
                    list[4].ForeColor = TextColor[4];
            }

            CheckTexts();
        }

        private void CheckTexts()
        {
            Label prev = null;
            foreach (Label l in this.list)
            {
                if (l != null)
                {
                    using (Graphics g = l.CreateGraphics())
                    {
                        SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(l.Text, l.Font);

                        int linesNeeded = (int)Math.Ceiling(sz.Width) / l.Width + 1;
                        l.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(sz.Height * linesNeeded);

                        if (prev != null)
                            if (l.ClientRectangle.IntersectsWith(prev.ClientRectangle))
                                l.Location = new Point(l.Location.X, prev.Location.Y + prev.Height + _spacing);

                        prev = l;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void startFeed()
        {
            try
            {
                {
                    // Set movement variables 
                    timer1.Interval = 50;
                    jump = 1;
                    // Start Timer 
                    timer1.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NewsFeeder Error: " + err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In general my project im dragging the UserControl NewsFeed to form1 designer and in the UserControl i feed text that move from the bottom to the top.
In the original in form1 i used my own text and colors in SetupText and SetupColors.

But now instead i want to use the text that is in the variable readableRss.
This is an example of the content of readableRss:

```
צפו: נפרד ממשפחתו ויוצא לבצע פיגוע התאבדות
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:18:39 +0200

סוף סוף: פורסמו הכרזים לבניה ברמת שלמה בי-ם
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:10:03 +0200

צפו בוידאו: משלחת של שרים וחכ''ים במחנה ההשמדה אושוויץ - השר אריאל אומר קדיש
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:09:25 +0200
```

So for example this part of the content in readabelRss:

```
סוף סוף: פורסמו הכרזים לבניה ברמת שלמה בי-ם
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:10:03 +0200
```

This two lines should be one block of text that should move from the bottom to the top.

Now this is what i see in lines:

In index 0 i see: "צפו: נפרד ממשפחתו ויוצא לבצע פיגוע התאבדות
And in index 1 i see: "Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:18:39 +0200"

There are 151 lines in this case now.

The variable t in the FOR loop contain now:

```
צפו: נפרד ממשפחתו ויוצא לבצע פיגוע התאבדות
```

In the next iteration the variable t contain:

```
Mon, 27 Jan 2014 19:18:39 +0200
```

What i want is that each text of a line and the next line of time and date under it will be move from the bottom to the top like in animation.
Its working with my code if im using my own text and colors but i want to use the text in the variable readableRss .

Comment: `Lines`' is an array of `string`. Why use the `Convert.ToString` method on a `string`?

Comment: Are you sure `SetupText` is being called?  Did you set a breakpoint?  Where is `counter` initialized?

Comment: 1) Show what is initial value of `counter` 2) show value of `readableRss` string 3) Show implementation of `SetupText` method 4) show where `t` is declared

Comment: Updated my question with the code a bit long but its all connected. And also i added what i see in the variables when using a breakpoint.

Comment: NewsFeed is a UserControl i added to my project with a timer in its designer set to 1000 ms interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As using the text `hi` works instead of the actual string value the only possibility is that the output of the `ConvertRss`method returns only newline characters or is empty. You should check the value of the `readableRss` variable.

Note that `t = Convert.ToString(lines[i]);` is useless as `lines` is an array of `string`.